# Conditional calculation on different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, mssql-jdbc

I have this table where I need to calculate different columns in SQL Server

[image: invoice_info]

So far, I have been able to calculate `line_item_total_gst` column using this formula `line_item_total_including_gst / 11` using the syntax below where the rows are null:

```
UPDATE dbo.invoice_info
    SET line_item_total_gst = line_item_total_including_gst / 11
WHERE line_item_total_gst IS NULL;
```

My question is how do I do a calculation based on a condition, for example if `gst_applicable` column is equal to 'Yes' then perform the calculation above. Else if `gst_applicable` is equal to 'No' then `line_item_total_gst` is 0.

Comment: You can use [CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) expression

Comment: How would you do that?

Comment: `CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END` Please refer to the link for documentation and example

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `case` expression:

```sql
UPDATE dbo.invoice_info
SET    line_item_total_gst = 
       CASE gst_applicable  WHEN 'Yes' THEN line_item_total_including_gst / 11
                            ELSE 0
       END
WHERE  line_item_total_gst IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for update:

```
UPDATE dbo.invoice_info
    SET line_item_total_gst = line_item_total_including_gst / 11
WHERE line_item_total_gst IS NULL AND gst_applicable ='YES';

UPDATE dbo.invoice_info
    SET line_item_total_gst = 0
WHERE line_item_total_gst IS NULL AND gst_applicable ='No';
```

If you want to select table with calculation:

```
SELECT
      gst_applicable
     ,line_item_total_excluding_gst
     ,CASE WHEN gst_applicable = 'Yes' AND line_item_total_gst IS NULL 
           THEN   line_item_total_including_gst / 11
      WHEN gst_applicable = 'Yes' AND line_item_total_gst IS NOT NULL
           THEN   line_item_total_gst 
      ELSE
                  0
      END AS line_item_total_gst
     ,line_item_total_including_gst 
FROM dbo.invoice_info
```